# Swiftui foreach looping on an array of buttons

Tags: swift, xcode, button, foreach, swiftui

when press a button in the loop, its background color changes to red and when pressing another button its color also changes to red. but the remaining button is still red does not change to blue again. How can I only change the pressed button to red and have the other buttons change to blue?

```
struct Box: Identifiable  {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
}

struct MainView: View {


    let boxes:[Box] = [
    Box(id: 0, title: "Home"),
    Box(id: 1, title: "Subjects"),
    Box(id: 2, title: "attendence"),
    Box(id: 3, title: "H.W"),
    Box(id: 4, title: "Quizes"),
    Box(id: 5, title: "class schedule"),
    Box(id: 6, title: "Exam Schedule"),
    Box(id: 7, title: "Inbox"),
    Box(id: 8, title: "Evalouation"),
    ]

    @Binding var showMenu: Bool

    var body: some View{
    VStack {
        ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false){
                HStack{
                    ForEach(boxes, id: \.id) {
                        box in
                        BoxView(box: box)
                    }

                }
            }


        }.padding()

    }
}

struct BoxView: View {
    @State var selectedBtn: Int = 1
    var box: Box
    var body: some View{
        Button(action: {
            self.selectedBtn = self.box.id

        }){
            Text(box.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    .frame(width: 130, height: 50)
        .background(self.selectedBtn == self.box.id ? Color.red : Color.blue)
    .cornerRadius(25)
    .shadow(radius: 10)
    .padding(10)

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI change background color of a button inside a scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984847/swiftui-change-background-color-of-a-button-inside-a-scrollview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

1) Add a `@State` to MainView keeping track of the selected button

2) Pass this state as a binding to BoxView

3) Change `@State` to a `@Binding` (= in-out state) on BoxView

```
struct MainView: View {
  [...]
  @Binding var showMenu: Bool
  @State var selected = 0    // 1
  var body: some View{
    VStack {
      ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false){
        HStack{
          ForEach(boxes, id: \.id) { box in
            BoxView(box: box, selectedBtn: self.$selected)  // 2
          }
        }
      }
    }.padding()
  }
}

struct BoxView: View {
  var box: Box
  @Binding var selectedBtn: Int  // 3 
  var body: some View{
    Button(action: {
      self.selectedBtn = self.box.id
    }){
      Text(box.title)
       .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    .frame(width: 130, height: 50)
    .background(self.selectedBtn == self.box.id ? Color.red : Color.blue)
    .cornerRadius(25)
    .shadow(radius: 10)
    .padding(10)
  }
}
```